# React: how change "const Todo = ({todo, todoList, remove}) => {" to "export default class Todo extends React.Component {"

Tags: reactjs

I have this component (at least, I think it is called "component"!):

```
const Todo = ({todo, todoList, remove}) => {
    let status = todo.opened ? 'opened' : 'closed';
    return (
        <li className={"todo " + status} data-endpoint={todo['@id']}>
            <form onChange={this.changeStatus}>
                <a href={window.Routing.generate('todo_list_todo_show', {account: todoList.account.id, list: todoList.id, todo: todo.id}, true)}>{todo.name}</a>
            </form>
        </li>
    );
}

export default Todo
```

Now I want to add some other methods to simply change the status of the Todo, setting it to open or closed checking a simple checkbox.

So I want to change the syntax to this:

```
export default class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render({todo, todoList, remove}) {
        let status = todo.opened ? 'opened' : 'closed';
        return (
            <li className={"todo " + status} data-endpoint={todo['@id']}>
                <form onChange={this.changeStatus}>
                    <a href={window.Routing.generate('todo_list_todo_show', {account: todoList.account.id, list: todoList.id, todo: todo.id}, true)}>{todo.name}</a>
                </form>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

This triggers an error:

> Todo.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'todo' of
>   undefined

The line 21 is the signature of the `render` method:

```
    render({todo, todoList, remove}) {
```

Why am I getting this error?

What changes between the two syntaxes? Is something related to JSX and hw the component is transpiled in pure Javascript?

How can I use the "full" syntax?

Which are the correct names to identify the first syntax and the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st is a stateless component, or a function component, that is passed the props and context as params. The 2nd is a class component, and the props are assigned to `this.props`. See [Components and Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) in the documentation.

The props are not passed to [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) as params. Destructure `this.props` to your variables.

```
render() {
    const {todo, todoList, remove} = this.props;
    const status = todo.opened ? 'opened' : 'closed';

    return (
        <li className={"todo " + status} data-endpoint={todo['@id']}>
            <form onChange={this.changeStatus}>
                <a href={window.Routing.generate('todo_list_todo_show', {account: todoList.account.id, list: todoList.id, todo: todo.id}, true)}>{todo.name}</a>
            </form>
        </li>
    );
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the `todo` is also the `state` of the component and I think, at this point, it's better to pass it as `data` to assign then it to `this.state.data`... am I understangin right?

Comment: No - `todo` is a prop passed to the component, and not part of it's state. You need to assign it to the state, only if you need to manipulate it in some way (here you only render it).

Comment: But then the parent (`TodoList`), and the `Todo` component will hold different states. Since you get the `todo` from the parent, the parent should handle the state, and the changes. The parent should pass a callback to the component, and the component should use the callback with the new state of open. The parent will update it's state, and will pass it back to the child.

Comment: I'll change its `state` with the method `changeStatus` referenced in the `form`. I'm going to implement the method and changing the component from a stateless one to a class one is the first step in implementing it.

Comment: O.O I think I need a new question o.O

I want the same `Todo` component be used in 1) a list of lists with each list showing its own todos; 2) in a single list view with the list showing its own todos and 3) in a Todo view.

In each one of the three lists I want the single todo be opened or closed. Implementing in the parent TodoList the logic to open and close the todo I will duplicate the code... For this reason I thought to implement it in the `Todo` component.

Comment: The `Todo` should handle the rendering, and the user input, but should relegate state management to a higher level. That is if there can be only one open `Todo` at each time. If there can be several open Todos, and the parent doesn't need to closed all of them, remove `open` from the `todo` object, and manage the open state inside the `Todo`.

Answer (score 0):

When using a function as a component, the function is passed props. When extending from `React.Component`, render isn't passed anything, but props are available on the instance as `this.props`.

So render needs to become:

```
render() {
  const { todo, todoList, remove } = this.props;
  // do your thing
}
```